# findOrCreate in Swift 3 without hardcoding entityName

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3, xcode8

Xcode 8 helpfully provides an automatically generated `extension` on your `NSManagedObject` subclasses, which looks like this:

```
//  Animal+CoreDataProperties.swift

import Foundation
import CoreData

extension Animal {

  @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Animal> {
    return NSFetchRequest<Animal>(entityName: "Animal");
  }

  // etc...
}
```

This is great because we no longer have to hardcode strings in order to create `NSFetchRequest` objects. However, Apple haven't provided a protocol to refer to this method, nor to the `entityName` itself.

For example, if I want to create a method like this:

```
protocol ManagedObjectType: class {}

extension ManagedObjectType where Self: NSManagedObject {

  static func findOrCreate(inContext context: NSManagedObjectContext, matchingPredicate predicate: NSPredicate) -> Self {
    // etc...
  }
}
```

... there is no way for me to take advantage of the `fetchRequest` method for any `NSManagedObject` subclass (because it's defined **only** on the subclasses), so I'm left having to hardcode these strings again myself (even though Xcode has already done that).

Does know a way to solve this? I was thinking something along these lines:

```
protocol ManagedObjectType: class {
  static func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>
}

extension Animal: ManagedObjectType {}
```

But this doesn't work because protocols don't support `where` clauses, so I can't specify that `Self` is an `NSFetchRequestResult`, which means that when I come to use it, like so:

```
let request: NSFetchRequest<Self> = self.fetchRequest()
```

... Xcode gives me this error:

> 'fetchRequest' produces 'NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>', not
>   the expected contextual result type 'NSFetchRequest<Self>'

Has anybody tackled this already?

Answer (score 1):

You can use templates for this purposes. So your code can look like this:

```
static func findOrCreate<T: NSManagedObject>(inContext context: NSManagedObjectContext, matchingPredicate predicate: NSPredicate) -> T {
    // etc...
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really work because I still can't call `fetchRequest` on `T`. However, I'm up-voting because your answer helped me to reach a solution (see above).

Comment: you can make it extension for NSManagedObject and then use like

Animal.findOrCreate(...)

and it'll be exactly the same, what you've achieved. correct me, if I'm wrong

Comment: You're right - you can do that, but it's somewhat misleading. `findOrCreate` will still use generics to return something of the appropriate type; the fact that the method has been called on the `Animal` class is irrelevant. For example, this would work fine: `let fruit: Fruit = Animal.findOrCreate(...)` (even though `Fruit` and `Animal` are not related at all).

Answer (score 1):

In the end, a slightly different approach worked for me.

First, define a `protocol` which uses an `associatedtype` - this is needed because you can't refer to `Self` as a generic type inside a `protocol` unless the class is marked as `final` (which it isn't in the case of auto-generated `NSManagedObject` subclasses):

```
protocol ManagedObjectType: NSFetchRequestResult {

  associatedtype ResultType: NSFetchRequestResult

  init(context: NSManagedObjectContext)
  static func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<ResultType>

}
```

You will need to add any `NSManagedObject` properties and methods here to which you need access in your helper methods. In my case, this is only the `init(context:)` initializer so far.

This makes it slightly more convoluted to mark your `NSManagedObject` subclasses as conformant:

```
extension Animal: ManagedObjectType {
  typealias ResultType = Animal
}
```

Now you can provide helper methods like so (notice the `where` clause):

```
static func findOrCreate<T: ManagedObjectType>(inContext context: NSManagedObjectContext, matchingPredicate predicate: NSPredicate, configure: (T) -> Void) -> T where T.ResultType == T {

  // You are now able to call fetchRequest like this:
  let request: NSFetchRequest<T> = T.fetchRequest()

  // etc...
}
```

Since the helper methods are no longer required to be defined on the `NSManagedObject` itself, you can put them anywhere really. I made them `static` methods inside a helper `struct`.